# Load JSX from an external string at runtime

Tags: reactjs

In my node.js program I have a data object `item`, and I'd like to let my user define a JSX template to that will format it as a string. That JSX template might look like:

```js
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:item.html}} />{item.meta.tags.map(t=>t.name)}
```

This is stored in an external configuration file that I load at runtime.

My best attempt is using [react-jsx-parser](https://github.com/TroyAlford/react-jsx-parser) like so:

```js
ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(React.createElement(JsxParser, { jsx: [as above], bindings: { item } }));
```

This doesn't work because the library [doesn't support functions](https://github.com/TroyAlford/react-jsx-parser/issues/107), but if I remove that it works ok. However I would like to support functions.

I feel like this functionality must be built into React somewhere, as at some point any JSX starts as a string that must be compiled... so how do I do it at runtime instead of during a build?

Comment: I'm running into the same problem: I would like to render dynamic HTML into the virtual DOM. Just dangerously setting inner html doesn't work since the markup contains custom components. It is a mystery to me why this is not supported. Sure, there would be a performance hit to compile JSX at runtime. But it should be possible. Well, I haven't found a way yet.